# Automated way to round number based on precision of error

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, rounding

I have a script that generates a large table of values and the corresponding errors. The errors calculated always have 1 significant figure but of varying precision (eg error1 = 1e-5 error2 = 1e-1). I was wondering if there an automated logical way of rounding of the values in the table based on the precision of the error.
For example, I would like to go from Table 1 to Table 2 (given below) in an automated manner (in python).

```
Table 1
A          B          C
error      error      error
0.0300     61.7303    39.9862
2e-02      5e-01      2e+00


Table 2
A          B          C
error      error      error
0.03       61.7       40
2e-02      5e-01      2e+00
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at python's decimal class?
Take a look at this extensive read regarding rounding numbers in python, it contains all the information you need to solve your issue:
https://realpython.com/python-rounding/